# Nebular stepper Issue after completed

Tags: angular, sass, angular6, nebular

I need help in nebular stepper, as we know that when the any step completed then the "checkmark" icon displayed but my use case is different I need the number will remain but color will change as same as icon (i.e. # ffffff).

I am not able to override the scss for this. Please advise how can I override.

Please find the screenshots of expected and current behavior:

[image: Current Behavior]

[image: Expected Behavior]

```
<nb-card class="card">
<nb-card-body>
    <nb-stepper orientation="horizontal">
        <nb-step [label]="labelOne">
            <ng-template #labelOne></ng-template>
            <h3>Working on Step 1</h3>
        </nb-step>
        <nb-step [label]="labelTwo">
            <ng-template #labelTwo></ng-template>
            <h3>Step 1 completed... Working on Step 2</h3>
        </nb-step>
        <nb-step [label]="labelThree">
            <ng-template #labelThree></ng-template>
            <h3>Step 2 completed... Working on Step 3</h3>
        </nb-step>
        <nb-step [label]="labelFour">
            <ng-template #labelFour></ng-template>
            <h3>Step 3 completed... Working on Step 4</h3>
        </nb-step>
    </nb-stepper>
</nb-card-body>
```

Comment: Your code will help us so much.

Comment: HI, I am using the default Nebular scss, tried to override but not able to do so. HTML code is  i have attached.

Comment: @3rdthemagical, could you help me out in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never worked with Nebular.
According to [API](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/stepper/api) there is no way to define custom template for step mark. [Source code](https://github.com/akveo/nebular/blob/master/src/framework/theme/components/stepper/stepper.component.html) of component does not provide modification of step mark too.

Anyway you can replace checkmark symbol with [css counters](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/counter-increment/). But it's very tricky solution:

```
nb-stepper {
    counter-reset: stepper;
}

nb-stepper .step {
    counter-increment: stepper;
}

nb-stepper .nb-checkmark::before {
    content: counter(stepper) !important;
}
```